# Visual Studio 2010: Where are the AJAX Extensions?

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2010

I'm interested in using an AJAX extension, namely this textbox calendar control.

Has anyone else ever had a hard time getting any AJAX controls to show up?

[image]

Surely all the excitement about AJAX isn't from the six controls listed above.

Would this be a corrupt install?

I've changed my Project's Target framework down from `.NET Framework 4` to `.NET Framework 3.5`, closed VS2010 and reopened it. Still the same.

I also tried a Right-Click and selected **Reset Toolbox**, but that did nothing either.

What's going on? Am I the only one having this problem?

Comment: Dude, it's been many years since there was any excitement about the AJAX stuff in ASP.NET Web Forms. :)

Comment: LOL - well, it's all new to me. I'm finally breaking out of the WinForm mold. Embrace WebForms!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the [ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/).
They aren't built-in.

Comment: I installed that one. *Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages...*, and I see I have AjaxControlToolkit installed. The directions said to create a new tab called `AJAX Toolbox`, browse to where you installed the toolkit, and add the items. Well, I can't find where the silly toolkit installed itself!

Comment: In `packages\AjaxControlToolkit` or something like that in your solution folder.

Comment: Never would have guessed that! So, every time I start a new project, I should go back into the `AJAX Toolbox` and re-point to all of the `AJAX` controls? Oh, and that added them all, by the way!